# A Kind of Weird of Differential Equation Notation, Writing Error or Not?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation, terminology

I have this kind of Weird DE from someone i know:

$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}(y-1) = \dfrac{dy}{dx}$

1. If i ignore the extra $y$ in the $d^2$ then i interpret it as the

   DE of the third order of $y$ with respect to $x$ :

   $\dfrac{d^3y}{dx^3} -\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \dfrac{dy}{dx} \to y^{(3)} - y^{(2)} =    y^{(1)}$
2. Or is it :

   $\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}(y^2) -\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \dfrac{dy}{dx} $

I dont even know what (2) even mean

This guy also hinted that a Non-Elementary Integral is involved in solving it (Exponential Integral).

My Question :

1. Is it the DE of the third order or maybe just mistake in writing it ?
2. If it makes sense then is my interpretation right ? if not what's the correct interpretation ?
3. If it makes sense is it solvable ?
4. If it's solvable, is it really involving the Non-Elementary function as he hinted ?

Comment: Your equation has no elementary solution

Comment: What's the correct interpretation of the notation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it easier switching variables
$$y''(y-1) = y'\implies -\frac {x''}{[x']^3}(y-1)=\frac 1 {x'}$$ Assuming $x' \neq 0$, we need to solve
$$[x']^2+(y-1)x''=0$$ Reduction of order $p=x'$
$$(y-1)p'+p^2=0 \implies p=x'=\frac{1}{\log (|1-y|)+c_1}$$ Integrating again
$$x+c_2=-e^{-c_1}\, \text{Ei}(c_1+\log (|1-y|))$$ Inversing leads to @JJacquelin 's result.

Comment: Is my result correct ? I have posted my own answer below.

Answer (score 4):

It is an ODE with non-constant coefficients. Writing it as
$$
(y - 1) y'' = y'
$$
may clarify. If not, think of it as
$$
g(y) y'' = y',
$$
where $g(y) = y - 1$.

It is then clearly a second order equation. I don't know about solvability, sorry.

Comment: hm.. this might make the most sense. Yeah only he knows what it means

Comment: I'm sorry if I was misleading. I am not guessing, this is what it is.

Answer (score 3):

$$y''(y-1) = y'$$
A trivial solution is $y'=0\quad\implies\quad y=$constant.

General case $y(x)\neq$ constant :
$$y''=\frac{y'}{y-1}$$
integration :
$$y'=\ln|y-1|+c_1$$
$$\frac{y'}{\ln|y-1|+c_1}=1$$
$$\int \frac{dy}{\ln|y-1|+c_1}=x+c_2$$
$$e^{-c_1}\text{Ei}(\ln|y-1|+c_1)=x+c_2$$
$\text{Ei}$ is the Exponential integral function: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html
$$\text{Ei}(\ln|y-1|+c_1)=e^{c_1}(x+c_2)$$
$$(\ln|y-1|+c_1)=\text{Ei}^{-1}\left(e^{c_1}(x+c_2)\right)$$
$\text{Ei}^{-1}$ is the inverse function of the Exponential integral function.

The solution of the ODE is:
$$y(x)=1+\exp\bigg(\text{Ei}^{-1}\big(e^{c_1}(x+c_2)\big)-c_1\bigg)$$

Answer (score 2):

There is no error in notation or anything. I will rewrite it for you:
$$(y-1)\dfrac {\textrm d^2y}{\textrm dx^2}=\dfrac {\textrm dy}{\textrm dx} $$
The confusing term was essentially the product of the double derivative and the factor of $y-1$.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Answer (score 0):

I have my own solution for this, let me know which steps are incorrect.

Let $t = y' \to t' = y''$, so the DE becomes:

$y''(y-1) = y' \to t'(y-1) = t$

$y = \dfrac{t}{t'} + 1$

$y' = t = \dfrac{t'\cdot t' - t\cdot t''}{(t')^2}$

$t = 1-t\cdot \dfrac{t''}{(t')^2}$

$ \dfrac{t''}{(t')^2} = \dfrac{1}{t} - 1$

$ \dfrac{t''}{t'} = \dfrac{t'}{t} - t'$

$\displaystyle \int\dfrac{t''}{t'} = \int\left(\dfrac{t'}{t} - t'\right)$

$\ln(t') = \ln(t) - t$

$t' = \dfrac{t}{e^t}$

$\displaystyle \int\dfrac{e^{t}}{t} \;dt = \int dx$

$\text{Ei}(t) = \text{Ei}(y') = x + C_1$

$y' = \text{Ei}^{-1}(x+C_1)$

$y = C_2 + \displaystyle \int \text{Ei}^{-1}(x+C_1)\; dx$

i'm not sure about the result above because the result of $y$ is a function one level above the non-elementary function $Ei$. Meanwhile the original one is actually just the inverse of $Ei$